# Why is my background color not displaying?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got this CSS:

```
.backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

and am trying to use it this way, along with an existing Bootstrap class:

```
<div class="jumbotron backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue" >
```

But the div's background color is not changing. The "jumbotron" class did have a background color defined, but I commented it out, and still no change...

Comment: Something is overriding it? Try `!important`?

Comment: Can't you just check your page in any normal browser's devtools - and see which rule is applied?

Comment: @Clay Shannon Did you get this problem solved? Would like to know why that style did not show. :)

Comment: It was a caching issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `!important` is not recommended. Try to debug why style is not applied. Try selector which is more specific. Example:

```
#someParentDiv .jumbotron.backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

> !important declarations should not be used unless they are absolutely
>   necessary after all other avenues have been exhausted. If you use
>   !important out of laziness, to avoid proper debugging, or to rush a
>   project to completion, then you’re abusing it, and you (or those that
>   inherit your projects) will suffer the consequences.

Read more: [When Should !important Be Used?](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue {
  background-color: lightskyblue !important;
}
```

maybe some other styles override this one, take a look at your element with firebug or similar tool

yes, i know that !important isn't recommended

but many plugins use this trick in their CSS, because they don't know about your DOM structure
and they wouldn't do something like:

```
#parentDiv .backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue
```

Comment: Nope; makes no difference.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `!important` modifier unless absolutely necessary. It's much better to use a more specific selector based approach. For example using `div.backgroundcolorLightSkyBlue {...}` should also yield the desired results. More on selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).